# Excel If/Then with Cell Contents for True Result

Tags: excel

I have several hundred phone numbers in column C.
I have several thousand phone numbers in columns AO & AP.
I want to determine if a cell reference (phone number) in column C occurs in columns AP or AO.
If true, then I want to report the contents of the cell in column AM (name associated with the phone number) of the same row in which the phone number was found in column Y or Z.  I want this information reported into the cell in column E in the row of the phone number referenced in column C.

This is what I have so far and it almost works but I get no true reports back even though I can see the phone numbers in Columns C and AP or AP.

=IF(COUNTIF($AO$4:$AP$17000,(INDIRECT("c"&ROW())))=(INDIRECT("c"&ROW())),(INDIRECT("am"&ROW())),"N/A")

Help.

Thank you.

Comment: If you can sort the numbers in AO & AP, then you could use `VLOOKUP` to find matches.

Comment: Could you copy AM into AQ?

Answer (score 1):

I think you should try `MATCH` and `INDEX`. Here is how it is used:

For example you have thousands phone number reference on column A and names associated with phone numbers in column B.

Then, you have hundreds of phone numbers in column J.

If you want to know which phone numbers in column A that also exist in column J use:

> =MATCH(A1,J:J,0)

Put that formula in column C and you will get row number of the existing phone number in column J. If the phone number does not exist, it will return `#N/A`

If you simply want to check if the phone number exist in column J use:

> =NOT(ISERROR(MATCH(A1,F:F,0)))

That formula will simply return `TRUE` if phone number exist and `FALSE` if it does not exist

If you want to know names associated with phone number in column J according to reference in column A and B use:

> =INDEX(B:B,MATCH(J1,A:A,0))

Put that formula in column K and you will get names associated with phone number in column J.